# Determine all equivalence classes of $xy>0$

Tags: equivalence-relations

Define the equivalence relation $R$ as follows: For $x,y\in\mathbb R$, $x$ is equivalent to $y$ if and only if $xy\geq 0$. Determine all of the equivalence classes of this equivalence relation.

Comment: your title doesn't match your question.  Do you mean $>$ or $\geq$?

Answer (score 2):

The title doesn't match the question.  I'll use the wording from the question.  As written in your question (not the title), $R$ is *not* an equivalence relation; $0$ is equivalent to $1$, and $-1$ is equivalent to $0$, but $-1$ is not equivalent to $1$, so $R$ is not transitive.

If you mean what the title says ($x$ is equivalent to $y$ if $xy > 0$), then $R$ is not an equivalence relation, but for a different reason.  I'll leave it up to you to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : $xy \ge 0$ is $x$ and $y$ both have same sign or one among them is zero.

Comment: I have determined this is an equivalence relation on R, but am unsure of how to describe all the equivalence classes of this equivalence relation. They must be real numbers with the same sign, but is that all I need to know establish all equivalence classes? {x>0, y>0:x,y exist in  R} {x<0,y<0} {x<0,y=0} {x>0,y=0} {x=0,y<0} {x=0,y>0} ?

Comment: note that your equivalence class is a partition of $\mathbb{R}$